# ConstraintLayout - Applying both Group and Barrier, visibility gone not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

With the last version of `ConstraintLayout` (1.1.0-beta6), I have a weird behaviour when I use both `Barrier` and `Group` together.

Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_center_left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_top"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_center_right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_top"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view_center_right, view_center_left"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/view_center_barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view_center_right, view_center_left"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_center_barrier"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I set the `android:visibility` attribute of the `Group` to `visible`, here is my Blueprint render:

[image: Render with visibility = visible]

But when I set the `android:visibility` attribute of the `Group` to `gone`, here is what I get:

[image: Render with visibility = gone]

I expected to have the `view_bottom` below the `view_top` even if the visibility of the `Group` is `gone` but it's not below. Without the `Barrier`, this works perfectly.

How can I use a `Barrier` coupled with a `Group` and have a good behaviour when the visibility is set to `gone`?

Comment: What version exactly? It works fine with 1.1.0-beta4

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the version on my post. It's the 1.1.0-beta6